# How to get ASPxPopupControl appeared from (previosly) hidden button?

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls, devexpress

I want to show up an ASPxPopupControl whenever an user click a button. But there's a problem with this. The button belongs to a panel, which is hidden by default. It's only shown when user tells it to do so.

If the panel is initially visible, the popup control shows just fine. But if it's initially invisible (set by attribute `Visible="false"`), then when even the panel shows up, the popup control never appears!

How can I fix this? I know that I should ask this question in Devexpress forums, but it never hurts if I try here, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `ASPxPanel` control?  If so, try to use the panel's `ClientVisible` property instead of `Visible`. Does this help?

**UPDATE**

I would suggest that you start using the `ASPxPanel` instead and use its `ClientVisible` property.  If you want to use the standard `Panel`, you should hide it using the `style.visibility` property:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Green">
Test Panel
</asp:Panel>
<input type="button" value="show panel"
       onclick="document.getElementById('Panel1').style.visibility='';" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostBack)
        Panel1.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET panel, is there any workaround for this? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think by putting Visible = false in the server side code will not render the control to the browser. So we can't access it via DOM. I think you need to set the style instead of Visible property.